# merge rows of a csv based on same column value

Tags: powershell

```
Entity          Entry type                               Time       
------          ----------                               ----       
abab            Recording stopped                        10:48:01 AM
abab            Recording started                        10:49:14 AM
fghi            Recording stopped                        10:11:40 AM
fghi            Recording started                        10:12:13 AM
fghi            Recording stopped                        11:13:01 AM
fghi            Recording started                        9:14:13 AM 
tr              Recording stopped                        8:45:01 AM 
tr              Recording started                        11:14:18 AM
```

I have a csv file this and i want the data for same entity column values in same row. 
For eg: the data "`abab`" will be in single line.
I am trying to implement this through power shell.
Sorry if doubt is too basic.

Comment: Do you want the grouped data to be output to an object in Powershell or back out to the CSV? If you want it in the CSV, it will look rather clunky. You can use `group-object -property entity` for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your CSV input file

> ```
> "Entity","Entry type","Time"
> "abab","Recording stopped","10:48:01 AM"
> "abab","Recording started","10:49:14 AM"
> "fghi","Recording stopped","10:11:40 AM"
> "fghi","Recording started","10:12:13 AM"
> "fghi","Recording stopped","11:13:01 AM"
> "fghi","Recording started","9:14:13 AM"
> "tr","Recording stopped","8:45:01 AM"
> "tr","Recording started","11:14:18 AM"
> ```

Then you could merge the stop- and start recording times with something like this:

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path 'THE PATH TO YOUR INPUT CSV FILE'

$result = $csv | Group-Object Entity | ForEach-Object {
    $name = $_.Name
    $stopTime = $null
    foreach ($entity in $_.Group) {
        if (!$stopTime) { $stopTime = $entity.Time } 
        else { 
            [PsCustomObject]@{
                'Entity' = $name
                'Recording stopped' = $stopTime
                'Recording started' = $entity.Time 
            }
            $stopTime = $null      
        }
    }
}

# output on screen
$result

# output to new CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'THE PATH TO YOUR OUTPUT CSV FILE' -NoTypeInformation
```

The result on screen will look like:

> ```
> Entity Recording stopped Recording started
> ------ ----------------- -----------------
> abab   10:48:01 AM       10:49:14 AM      
> fghi   10:11:40 AM       10:12:13 AM      
> fghi   11:13:01 AM       9:14:13 AM       
> tr     8:45:01 AM        11:14:18 AM
> ```

Since there are 4 entries for entity `fghi` in the input file, this will lead to a result where there are two entries in the output for that entity.